# Google form at specific time

Tags: google-forms

Is it possible to create a Google form that will accept responses only during a particular time period?

Answer (score 3):

My initial response is **yes**.

How?  You'll have to look into [Google App Scripts](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/).  You're probably better off creating a [form via script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/form) and then creating a function that validates the dates and times.  So perhaps the pseudo code would be...

```
function main() {

    // Get today's date and the final date for the form to accept responses
    //
    var todaysDate = new Date();
    var endingDate = new Date(2014, 1, 31);

    if (todaysDate > endingDate) {
        // form no longer accepts responses
    }

    else buildForm();
}
```

This is the main idea.  Since I'm strapped for time, I'll come back later in the day to clarify this answer if need be.  Let me know if you have any questions or would like me to provide you with more examples.

---

**Reference**

[Google Apps Script: Form API](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/)